# Upgrading Cassandra

Tags: upgrade, cassandra

my Cassandra version is `1.2.4` and i'm trying to upgrade it to `2.0.5` and i know that in the first part i have to upgrade it to `1.0.14` and after that try to upgrade it to the `2.0.5` ,

when I try to run `nodetool -h localhost removenode Host ID` it gives me :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot remove self
>       at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.removeNode(StorageService.java:3199)
>   .....

before running that command i tried `nodetool upgradesstables`

what is the problem ? and how can i resolve it ?

---

OS:Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Comment: wait what ? upgrading 1.2.4 to 1.0.14 ? there is a typo ?

Answer (score -1):

is there multiple node on your cluster ?

if not, just drain the node and close it...